# Why doesn't my Mongoose Schema unique validation work for the first run?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When I first run my code (no collection in MongoDB), it works. When I run it a second time and a collection already exists, I get an error: `duplicate key error collection: exampledb.testusers index: skills.name_1 dup key: { : "CSS" }`

```
const required = true;
const unique = true;
const schema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    skills: [new Schema({
        _id: false,
        name: { type: String, required, unique },
        level: { type: Number, default: 0 }
    })]
});

const User = mongoose.model("user", schema);

const fakes = [];
for (let i = 50; i > 0; i--) {
    fakes.push({
        username: "CoolZero91",
        skills: [
            { name: "JavaScript", level: 9 },
            { name: "CSS", level: 7 }
        ]
    });
}

await User.create(fakes);
```

Shouldn't I get the same error for the first time as well? What is different when with the unique validation when I don't have an existing collection versus when I DO have an existing collection?

Comment: MongoDB unique indexes, and mongoose, enforce uniqueness between documents, not within a single document.

Comment: @Joe sure, but when I don't have a collection at all and I insert 50 documents as in my question, the uniqueness is not enforced. When I do have a collection, *then* the uniqueness is enforced. Why that happens is my question.

Comment: @Joe The more I think about this it seems that this is a bug in the `.create()` function of Mongoose - when there is no collection it adds the index only _after_ inserting the first batch of documents.

Comment: When I test that code with mongoose 6.0, it doesn't create any indexes at all, and it runs repeatedly, inserting 50 documents each time.

Comment: Under the hood create method calls the save method which inserts your documents one by one. You get to see all added but its like add one and then another and so on. Check the description here https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.create

Comment: @tbhaxor makes sense, but still doesn't explain why I don't get the same result every time; why is the 1st run different

Comment: Can you please check if the index exists? Also try to connect mongoose with createIndices option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back now, I'm pretty sure this was (or is) an issue with the way uniqueness is checked by indexes.

The Mongoose schema makes an index into the database that enforces the uniqueness. That doesn't (or didn't) seem to happen for the first set of inserts, so the first inserts were *not* checked for uniqueness by the index! I think this happens if the first insert is batch OR and individual thing - ergo; first-insert batches are not checked for uniqueness.

Thanks @tbhaxor in comments